# C Scanf: What does a return value of -1 mean?

Tags: c, error-handling, return-value, scanf

I'm writing a program that scans input from stdin (well it's supposed to anyways). At a certain point in the program, I need to scan an int using scanf. I've tried a few other functions as well and they all seem to result in the same error - they are returning -1. I assume this means there was some error in gathering data/variable assignment, but I can not find documentation on what kind of error this indicates. The code I wrote is shown below:

```
int selection = 4; //default value for selection - it has no meaning.
//printf("DATA SET ANALYSIS\n1. Show all the data.\n2. Calculate the average for an experiment.\n3. Calculate the averae across all experiments.\n4. Quit. \nSelection:__\n");
printf("Return value of scanf: %d\n", scanf("%d", &selection));
printf("Return value of getchar: %d\n", getchar());
printf("Unchanged value of selection: %d\n", selection);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Return value of scanf: -1
Return value of getchar: -1
Unchanged value of selection: 4
```

What is the source and meaning of this error? I am choosing not to put up the rest of my code. If it is impossible to assess the error without the rest of the code, I can put that up in an edit, but as I'm not sure of the source of the error, that would involve a lot of code. Thank you for any solutions.

Comment: For reference about C stuff, I like [POSIX 1.2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/); [fscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) is documented there. *Note: the returned value isn't necessarily `-1`; it is `EOF` (a negative value)*

Comment: In some cases the return value may be 0 as in `scanf("xyz%d", &i)` where input was "xyzabc".

Answer (score 3):

As is specified in the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf), the return value is positive if the reading succeeded or EOF (which is usually -1) if a reading error occured or end of file is reached.

Using the information you provided, it is impossible to find the actual error source, but I suggest you take a look at your stdin and how it is handled.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know EOF was equivalent to -1. Thank you. I'll look around to see if I can solve it now.